# Move selected text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I've been looking in the Notepad++ shortcuts and options for something that permits me to move selected  text in any direction, but I couldn't find anything.

There are two commands I use very often that offer similar functionality "Move Up Current Line" and "Move Down Current Line" but they apply to an entire line and I need something to work with just a selected text.

That functionality is very useful for rearranging columns or elements inside arrays.

Do you know a way to do this? Or maybe an extension or macro?

**Edit:**

Here some graphical examples of the functionality I wish:

You have some code:
[image]

You notice a expression is not in the right place. Why copy-paste? Why not move it?
[image]

Or even set it in the previous line, just using the arrow keys:
[image]

The idea is to move the selected text as a unit.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you want? The text before and the text after the move.

Comment: @M42 I just added some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand well what is your request, but, is that what you want:

- select with the mouse the part you want to move (ie. `var c = 34;`)
- keep pressed the left bouton
- drag the selected text to the line above
- drop it at the right place

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I wanted. I was thinking in a keyboard shortcut but with the mouse is even easier. Thanks!

Comment: It also works with the column mode explained by @Pankaj Jaju.

Comment: I want to disable this feature. Moving text with the mouse, for me, always happens by mistake.

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to move an entire row with a keyboard shortcut.

Place your curson on the line you want to move (not needed to select anything, just position the text insertion point in the row) then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> [or <kbd>down</kbd>]

The row moves accordingly of one row at once.

Keep pressed to move faster.

Comment: It's useful to know, but the OP knew it already. Read the questions carefully, he was looking for something to move **some selected text** vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

You can move columnar data easily

1- Suppose you have columnar data as shown in the picture below. So press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse Key Down</kbd>+<kbd>Drag Cursor</kbd> to select the column

[image]

2- Cut the text and then paste at desired place. Like in the picture below, I pasted it before first column

[image]

Refer: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Comment: Thank you for bringing the column mode example. Definitely it works in some cases but it is a little bit annoying to copy and paste every time. Also, it didn't work if your data is not a block.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Macro
1) select text
2) Macro => Start Recording
3) Copy
4) Search => Style One Token => Using 1st Style
5) 2 arrow key Right
or: Left, Up, Down, Right
or: Ctrl + Left, Ctrl + Up, Ctrl + Down, Ctrl + Right
6) Paste
7) Search => Jump Up => 1st Style
8) Search => Select and Find Next
9) Search => Style One Token => Using 1st Style
10) 2 Search => Jump Up => 1st Style
11) Cut
12) Search => Jump Down => 1st Style
13) Search => Clear Style => Clear 1st Style
14) Macro => Stop Recording
15) Save Current Recorded Macro...
16) Nume
17) Ctrl + Alt + Right
or: Ctrl + Alt + Left, Ctrl + Alt + Up, Ctrl + Alt + Down, Ctrl + Alt + Right
or: Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Left, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Up, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Down, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Right

 Macro v2
1) select text
2) Macro => Start Recording
3) Search => Clear Style => Clear 1st Style
4) Search => Style One Token => Using 1st Style
5) arrow key Right
or: Left, Right (Up No)
or: Ctrl + Left + Left, Ctrl + Right + Right
6) arrow key Shift + Right
or: Shift + Left, Shift + Up, Shift + Down, Shift + Right
or: Shift + Ctrl + Right, Shift + Ctrl + Left
7) Cut
8) Search => Jump Up => 1st Style
9) arrow key Left
or: Left, Right
10) Paste
11) Search => Jump Down => 1st Style
12) Search => Clear Style => Clear 1st Style
13) Macro => Stop Recording
14) Save Current Recorded Macro...
15) Nume
16) Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Right
or: Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Left, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Up, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Down, Shift + Alt + Ctrl + Right
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).